# How to increase number executors on jenkins build agent(kubernetes pods)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I have a pod template declared in configure clouds section and I am using jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4 image, build agents are coming up fine but they are coming up with just one executor, is there a way I can increase that number?

[image]

The reason I would like to increase the number of executors is, I want to create a job which triggers other jobs sequentially and I want to all the downstream projects to run on the same agent as the main job.

I don't see any option in configure cloud section, any heap or clue on workarounds is appreciated.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue with the same situation.

I found a post which similiar with this situation,maybe the [kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) is as same as [amazon-ecs plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs/),they both hard coded the executors value as 1.

[Jenkins inbound-agent container via ecs/fargate plugin - set # executors for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569887/jenkins-inbound-agent-container-via-ecs-fargate-plugin-set-executors-for-nod)

So, run pipeline steps one by one is the only way I know to avoid this issue.
If you need call other job,set *wait:false* would be work, like this

build(job: "xxxx", **wait: false**, parameters: [string(name: "key", value: "value")])