# Jenkins inbound-agent container via ecs/fargate plugin - set # executors for node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am currently utilising the [amazon-ecs plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs/) ([with jenkins/inbound-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent/)) to dynamically create agents in an attempt to reduce my teams dependancy on a single build master.

Without going into too much detail, essentially I would like the ability to have child jobs called by by my pipeline to run on the same agent already dynamically built by the above plugin (parent pipeline).
The jobs themselves are not process intensive but can run for a little while, so it would be ideal to not have such time intensive tasks being run on the master while avoiding the time it takes to spin up another ECS task for something so minor.

Ive gotten to the point where the child job being called by my pipeline tries to run on the temporary agent automatically created by the pipeline, but it gets stuck in a "Waiting for next available executor on XXXX" state.

From what i can tell the agent created by the amazon-ecs plugin only has 1 executor on it, but I cant find a way to configure this to say 2 on creation.
Is there a way to define the number of executors on a node on start up?

Master Jenkins Version = 2.332.1

Answer (score 1):

I ended up discovering that the number of executors the amazon-ecs-plugin sets on new agents had a hard coded value of 1.
Ive submitted a pull request with changes to make this configurable. Hopefully will get approved soon.

Further details available here:

- [github.com/jenkinsci/amazon-ecs-plugin/issues/265](https://github.com/jenkinsci/amazon-ecs-plugin/issues/265)
- [github.com/jenkinsci/amazon-ecs-plugin/pull/264](https://github.com/jenkinsci/amazon-ecs-plugin/pull/264)